# Laravel query showing different Result in DB::Table and DB::Select with inner join

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-9

I'm using 3 table
1.organizations
2.users
3.organization_user

So the organization_user is the pivot table for getting org. and user.

```
DB::select("SELECT users.name 'User Name',organizations.name 'Org Name'
   FROM users INNER JOIN organization_users ON 
organization_users.user_id=users.id
    INNER JOIN organizations ON 
organizations.id=organization_users.organization_id
   WHERE organization_users.organization_id=$org_id");
```

And getting the below result

> [
> {
> "User Name": "Navid Anjum",
> "Org Name": "org1"
> },
> {
> "User Name": "kamal",
> "Org Name": "org1"
> } ]

But when using

```
DB::table('organization_users')
        ->join('users','users.id','=','organization_users.user_id')
        ->join('organizations','organizations.id','=',
        'organization_users.organization_id')
        ->select('users.name as Name','organizations.name as Org Name')
        ->where('organization_users.id','=',$org_id)
        ->get();
```

And getting the below result

> [
> {
> "Name": "Navid Anjum",
> "Org Name": "org1"
> } ]

So What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have different where conditions. The second query search for a organizations_users.id instead organization_users.organization_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you not set the right id for organization_users in the second statement :

```
DB::table('organization_users')
    ->join('users','users.id','=','organization_users.user_id')
    ->join('organizations','organizations.id','=',
    'organization_users.organization_id')
    ->select('users.name as Name','organizations.name as Org Name')
    ->where('organization_users.organization_id','=',$org_id)
    ->get();
```